# Surface elements on the screen

Tags: java, android, size, screen, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` in her  LinearLayoutA, LinearLayoutB, LinearLayoutC and fragment.
I would like to fragment occupied 3/6 of the screen, LinearA 1/6, LinearB 1/6, LinearC 1/6,
So far, I set the height in `dp`, but this is not good idea for devices with different screen size.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Can you provide your xml or something similar to help me understand your purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a linearlayout use layout:weight for the views inside linearlayout and set their(views inside linearlayout) height to 0dp.